# How do I deal with Google Group spam pretending to be from Google group?

Tags: google-groups, spam-prevention

I have a closed google group that I administrate as the only owner. Only members are allowed to send email to this group. For purposes of this example, let's say it's called "my-group". Normal users receive mail that says it is from `my-group@googlegroups.com` when a group member sends mail to the group address.

Recently the group spam filter has filtered many messages purporting to be from `my-group@googlegroups.com`. This is the spam filter for the google group, not the spam filter for my email account. This address is not a member of the group; it is the group address. Can this address be safely blocking without breaking normal group usage? Or is there another way to prevent messages that are not from the group from getting to the group spam filter?

Comment: So an unknown individual(s) is spoofing your group's return address to send spam to your group? Or would the spam filter catch *any* unauthorized sender?

Comment: @Raystafarian It appears that yes, an unknown individual (expected not to be a group member) is spoofing the group's address to send spam to the group. The group is closed, so senders that are not members of the group are not supposed to be able to send any messages to the group.

Answer (score 2):

There is a suggestion to change the settings below... taken from another site.

> *Right, this is a new spam technique - At least a dozen of my google groups have been spammed this way already.  If you reject the spam
>   messages, it sends an annoying rejection message to all the members of
>   the group!  To prevent it go to Manage > Settings > Moderation  and
>   set Spam Messages to "Immediately reject them".   Leave the spam
>   you've already got unmoderated and it will go away after 7 days (I
>   think).*

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a link to the source of your quotation to the answer.